# Trailing slash appended by http-proxy-middleware in requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, proxy

I am experiencing an issue with the `http-proxy-middleware` package in my React application. When using the middleware to set up a proxy, it automatically adds a trailing slash ("/") at the end of the proxied requests. I would like to provide more context and ask for assistance in resolving this problem.

Here is the content of my setupProxy.js file:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:5000/',
      changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: {
        "/api": "" // I have also tried using '^/api/': '/' but without success
      }
    }));
};
```

And here is my custom HttpService where I utilize axios:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const get = (url: string, config?: any) => {
    return axios.get(url, config);
};

export const post = (url: string, data: any, config?: any) => {
    return axios.post(url, data, config);
};
```

Despite my efforts to configure the proxy with the pathRewrite option, the trailing slash is still being appended to the requests. This behavior is causing issues when communicating with the proxied server, as it expects the requests without the trailing slash - the biggest problem is when I want to pass URL parameters like here:

```
        const generatedParams = generateURLparams(filtersData); //param1=test&param2=test2
        if (generatedParams) {
            get(`api/items?${generatedParams}`).then((res) => {
                setForecastItems([...res.data]);
            });
        }
```

And the result is: `http://localhost:5000/items/?param1=test&param2=test2` which is incorrect.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or insights on how to resolve this problem. Thank you in advance for your help!